# Round up a DATETIME to midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying and struggling to round a date up, say:

```
 2011-08-26 11:33:21.653
```

To:

```
 2011-08-26 23:59:59.999
```

It just needs to round up to midnight, minus one micro-second. All the rounding functions I can find seem to only round integers or float values.

Answer (score 2):

Rounding today's date to 3 milliseconds before midnight today:

```
select DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,'20010101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'2001-01-01T23:59:59.997')
```

(Or for a column, variable, etc, substitute something else for CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

Answer (score 2):

Note that datetime is accurate to 3.33 milliseconds (1/300)

```
DATEADD(millisecond, -3, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, '2011-08-26 11:33:21.653'), 1))
```

Note, if this is for a range query, then usually you do this:

```
DateCol >= '20110826' AND DateCol < '20110827'
```

...not these

```
DateCol >= '20110826' AND DateCol <= '2011-08-26 23:59:59.997'
DateCol BETWEEN '20110826' AND '2011-08-26 23:59:59.997'
```